# Component install error: JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have created a component simply by following this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q_a5g3gEMM). I have created my component named admin.zip. I am getting this following warning while installing in joomla 3.0.

> Warning
>
> JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\wamp\www\Content\tmp\install_52009de34a2c1\site\language\en-GB.com_helloworld.ini
>
> JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\wamp\www\Content\tmp\install_52009de34a2c1\admin\language\en-GB.com_helloworld.ini

I am getting helloworld component under component menu. but when i click on it it gives me error . It should show me Hello world as shown in the video.

my wamppserver version is 2.4 and using joomla 3.0.

how can i correct this problem

[The error while clicking on hello world component is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztSGx.jpg)

my helloworld.xml file contains this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

    <name>com_helloworld</name>
    <creationDate>November 2009</creationDate>
    <author>David Thorn</author>
    <authorEmail>info@thornwebdesign.org</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.example.org</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright Info</copyright>
    <license>License Info</license>
    <version>1.0.0.1</version>
    <description>Description of the Hello World component ...</description>
    <files folder="site">
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <folder>css</folder>
            <folder>js</folder>
            <folder>views</folder>
            <folder>models</folder>
            <folder>controllers</folder>
            <folder>helpers</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
        </files>
        <languages folder="site">
                        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
                        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>    
    <administration>
            <menu>com_helloworld</menu>
            <files folder="admin">
                <filename>index.html</filename>
                <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
                <filename>controller.php</filename>
                <folder>css</folder>
                <folder>js</folder>
                <folder>views</folder>
                <folder>models</folder>
                <folder>controllers</folder>
                <folder>helpers</folder>
                <folder>language</folder>
            </files>
            <languages folder="admin">
                        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
                        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
            </languages>            
    </administration>

 </extension>
```

In my helloworld.php i have this code

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JController::getInstance('Helloworld');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

 // Redirect if set by the controller
  $controller->redirect();
  ?>
```

**Update**

I did this successfully in joomla 2.5 but it is not working in the latest version of joomla. what should i do to make it work in joomla 3.0

Comment: It's telling you there's a file missing. Create the file.

Comment: I already have that php file in that specified location . After installing my component those files are created in those directories.

Comment: check your xml file some files are not extis also follow right tutorial from Joomla http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.1/Introduction

Comment: I have editted my question and shown my helloworld.xml file. Will you please tell me how to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have added this code to your XML:

```
<languages>
        <language tag="en-GB" client="site">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB" client="site">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworldt.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

and:

```
<administration>
... 
    <languages>
            <language tag="en-GB" client="site">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
            <language tag="en-GB" client="site">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
...
</administration>
```

and check if the files are included in your installation ZIP - in right folder, e.g.:

language/en-GB/ ...

Be aware, the path to the file can be different for your extension.

Jan

Comment: in my xml file i have

<languages folder="site">
<language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
       <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
      </languages> 
and also 

<languages folder="admin">
<language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
       <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>

Answer (score 1):

You are missing en-GB subfolder declaration in your xml file path. 
xml: language/en-GB.com_helloword.sys.ini while it should be language/en-GB/en-GB.helloworld.sys.ini
and path: language/en-GB/en-GB.helloworld.sys.ini
same pattern goes for the other language files of course.

*since your edit and source code inclusion,including your full xml code with the corrections (filepath and extension closing tag)

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<name>com_helloworld</name>
<creationDate>November 2009</creationDate>
<author>David Thorn</author>
<authorEmail>info@thornwebdesign.org</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>http://www.example.org</authorUrl>
<copyright>Copyright Info</copyright>
<license>License Info</license>
<version>1.0.0.1</version>
<description>Description of the Hello World component ...</description>
<files folder="site">
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <folder>models</folder>
        <folder>controllers</folder>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>
    <languages folder="site">
                    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
                    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>    
<administration>
        <menu>com_helloworld</menu>
        <files folder="admin">
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <folder>css</folder>
            <folder>js</folder>
            <folder>views</folder>
            <folder>models</folder>
            <folder>controllers</folder>
            <folder>helpers</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
        </files>
        <languages folder="admin">
                    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
                    <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>            
</administration>
```

`
(can not include the extension opening and closing tag, for some reason it wont be printed, please make sure to include them correctly)

for your other issue, in your helloworld.php you probably need to import the joomla controller library:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
```

after the

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
```

and replace this:

```
$controller = JController::getInstance('Helloworld');
```

with this one:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Helloworld');
```

Comment: I am having en-GB folder in which i have these two files /en-GB.helloworld.sys.ini and en-GB.com_helloworld.ini. also i have editted my question and shown my helloworld.php file where i have imported the joomla control library.

Comment: By mistakenly i haven't copied my last line of helloworld.xml. Closing extension tag is at the end of the line. Without extension tag i am getting error while installing the package. it says "JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file". Also, i would like to ask , just by adding JControllerLegacy in my php page will work in Joomla 3.0 or i have to do some other changes also.

Comment: is it working if you copy/paste the code i provided and include the <extension> tags? as for the JControllerLegacy, you can try it and let us know please. If any changes are needed you may consult this one http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder ="admin" from languages tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).